# IOS intercepts the string of the specified width

Tags: ios

[effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJI6C.png)The requirement is to intercept the display of the string 3/2 of the screen width over the display...

Hope to get your help, thank you!

```
if (meetModel.title.length > 18) {
    title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", [meetModel.title substringToIndex:18]];
} else {
    title = meetModel.title;
}
```

This method does not meet my needs. The page display is in Chinese.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "intercept the display of the string"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I uploaded a renderings, each line with a title, the title length can not exceed lable width, I want to display titles with a lable, so the question now is how to intercept the string of lable width. Thank you very much for your comments, but next time we will clean up the questions

Answer (score 1):

I didn't clearly understand your question, but I think you need to add something like this (the example is in Swift 3.1). The idea is that you should set the width constraint, and if the text larger than this width, it should be automatically truncated.

```
yourLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.66).isActive = true

// It's needed for adding three dots in the end, if the string is larger then it should be
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
```